# Retain textbox value after postback

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am using below CGI Perl code:

```
print <<EOF;
<table width=50% align='center'>
<tr>
<td align='right' width=40%>Sub Category: </td>
<td align='left' width=50%>
<select id='subcat' onchange="document.create_cont.submit();">
EOF

my $filename='SN_CatProduct.xml';
my $xs = XML::Simple->new();
my $config = $xs->XMLin($filename);
my $x = XML::Simple->new( ForceArray => 1);
#my $proc_config = $x->XMLin('SN_Procedures.xml');

my $last;
my $s_category = $config->{'category'}{'subcat'};
print "\n";
foreach my $key (sort (keys  %{$s_category})){
 #print "$s_category->{$key}{'sname'} <br>";
 my $subcat_val=$s_category->{$key}{'sname'};
 print "<option>".$subcat_val. "</option>";
 $last=$key;
}
my $val=$q->param("subcat");
print "<p>".$val."</p>";
print <<EOF;
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
EOF
```

While refreshing the page option value not retaining.

Plese help me to do this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not valid perl code. Please show us your valid code, and whatever errors you may be experiencing.

Comment: Flimzy I upadted my code.. Please help me to hold post back value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone!!

I have used cgi::ajax module. Now my issue has been resloved.

Answer (score 0):

When you are outputting the option tags, test to see if the value of the tag you are outputting matches the value in the submitted form data. If it does, add a `selected` attribute to it.

You'll probably find this easier to achieve if you store your option values/labels in an array (of hashrefs) then if you hard code the HTML for every option.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! If we are using variable instead of option values. How can we hold those values.